# Send CustomEvent from web component to Angular

Tags: angular, web-component

I have a web component that emits a `CustomEvent` to notify other components about a tenant change of the user.

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tenant-changed', { 
   detail: { 
       tenant: newTenant 
   }, 
   bubbles: true, 
   composed: true 
}));
```

I want to use this web component in an Angular 6 application. I tried to register for the `CustomEvent`, but somehow the Angular component does not get notified. I tried the following two approaches

```
ngOnInit() { 
     this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'tenant-changed', (event) => { 
         this.changeTenant(event); 
    }) 

    this.elementRef.nativeElement.queryElement('#my-filter').addEventListener('tenant-changed', this.changeTenant.bind(this)); 
 }
```

Or isn't this approach possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. First I have to use `window.dispatchEvent`instead of `this.dispatchEvent`.

Then it is easy in Angular to listen to this event using a regular event listener: `window.addEventListener('tenant-changed, this.changeTenant.bind(this))`

Comment: window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('my-event',{details:{}})) but with some reason it is not getting captured by onMyEvent function defined in components.ts any clue

Comment: You habe to add „bubbles:true“ within „details“

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to use Angular's [Event Binding Mechanism](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) to listen to a Web Component's dispatched events.

In your case it will look like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-filter (tenant-changed)="onTentantChanged($event)"></app-filter>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
onTentantChanged(event: CustomEvent){
    // do something spectacular!
}
```

Comment: unfortunately $event is seen as an Event object and you get this error: `Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomEvent<any>'.`

Comment: @GalenHowlett, this is actually the issue to which I'm searching for answers. Haven't been able to find anything yet.